# How SIGSEGV fault works if i try to print value of an address not in user space

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I was reading about the memory management implementation in linux. Got to know about memory segmentation so was trying to know about how memory is protected. I created a program to create a segmentation fault as below

```
void main()
{
    int a=10;
    for(int i=0;i<5000;i++)
    {
        printf("value is - %d",*(&a+i));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

that gives output as below using strace

```
write(1, "value is - 1937059584\n", 22value is - 1937059584
) = 22
write(1, "value is - 1768042354\n", 22value is - 1768042354
) = 22
write(1, "value is - 1701326702\n", 22value is - 1701326702
) = 22
write(1, "value is - 7302252\n", 19value is - 7302252
)    = 19
write(1, "value is - 0\n", 13value is - 0
)          = 13
write(1, "value is - 0\n", 13value is - 0
)          = 13
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR,       si_addr=0x7ffec6ddd000} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

Now, i want to know how write system call internally checks the access of memory based on the pointer provided, and how SIGSEGV gets handled from write system call.

Comment: That system call has pretty much nothing to do with it.

Comment: Memory protection is a part of modern processor architectures. An attempt to access unowned memory results in a "hardware fault", OS just handles the "hardware fault"

Answer (score 1):

> Now, i want to know how write system call internally checks the access of memory based on the pointer provided, and how SIGSEGV gets handled from write system call.

It doesn't.

The bad memory access is happening in your `main` function, in the code fragment:

```
*(&a+i)
```

This code is evaluated before `printf` is called at all, and long before it ends up calling `write`.

If `write` is passed an invalid pointer, it will return the error `EFAULT` -- it will not crash! `SIGSEGV` is only generated when code running within your process performs a bad memory access.

Comment: So how does it really checks the access of that evaluated address, I mean is there any other system call that is involved?? I heard that SIGSEGV gets thrown  from MMU itself but what happens behind the scenes?

Comment: @PiyushArora That's handled by the CPU; it raises an exception on a bad memory access, and the kernel translates that to a signal. System calls don't come into the picture at all.